# my faq is not getting added in the backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, rest

I want dispatch all the data to the database. In my case all the data is getting added except faqs. It's showing empty array when I dispatch `createProduct(myForm).`

but when I console,  It shows output in the console It shows output

```
for (let i = 0; i < faqs.length; i++) {
        myForm.set(`faqs[${i}][question]`, faqs[i].question);
        myForm.set(`faqs[${i}][answer]`, faqs[i].answer);
        console.log(myForm.get(`faqs[${i}][question]`));
        console.log(myForm.get(`faqs[${i}][answer]`));     
     }
```

NewProduct.js

```
import React from 'react'
import './NewProduct.css'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { useAlert } from 'react-alert'
import  { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import MetaData from '../MetaData'
import Sidebar from './Sidebar'
import { animalTypeLoadAction } from '../../actions/categories/animalTypeAction';
import { treatmentTypeLoadAction } from '../../actions/categories/treatmentTypeAction';
import { dailyEssentialsTypeLoadAction } from '../../actions/categories/dailyEssentialTypeAction';
import { medicalCareTypeLoadAction } from '../../actions/categories/medicalCareTypeAction';
import { MdAccountTree, MdAttachMoney, MdDescription, MdSpellcheck, MdStorage } from 'react-icons/md'
import { FiPenTool} from 'react-icons/fi'
import { NEW_PRODUCT_RESET } from '../../constants/productConstants';
import { clearErrors, createProduct } from '../../actions/productAction';
import { Button, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { FiHelpCircle } from "react-icons/fi";


const NewProduct = () => {


    const navigate =useNavigate();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const alert = useAlert();
    
    const { treatmentType } = useSelector(state => state.treatmentTypeAll)
    const { dailyEssentialType } = useSelector(state => state.dailyEssentialTypeAll)
    const { MedicalCareType } = useSelector(state => state.medicalCareTypeAll)
    const {animalType} = useSelector(state=> state.animalTypeAll)
 
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [price, setPrice] = useState(0);
    const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
    const [Stock, setStock] = useState(0);
    const [animal, setAnimal ] = useState();
    const [treatment, setTreatment ] = useState();
    const [dailyEssential, setdailyEssential ] = useState();
    const [medicalCare, setmedicalCare ] = useState();
    const [brand, setBrand] = useState("")
    const [size_of_instrument, setSize_of_instrument] = useState("")
    const [stage, setstage] = useState("")
    const [condition, setCondition] = useState("")
    const [varieties, setvarieties] = useState("")
    const [specific_feature, setSpecific_feature] = useState("")
    const [packaging_dimensions, setPackaging_dimensions] = useState("")
    const [mode_of_administration, setMode_of_administration] = useState("")
    const [caution, setCaution] = useState("")
    const [material_used, setMaterial_used] = useState("")
    const [model_number, setModel_number] = useState("")
    const [weight_of_the_commodity, setweight_of_the_commodity] = useState("")
    const [shelflife, setShelflife] = useState("")
    const [guarantee, setGuarantee] = useState("")
    const [imagesPreview, setImagesPreview] = useState([]);
    const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
    const [faqs, setFAQs] = useState([]);

    const { loading, error, success } = useSelector((state) => state.newProduct);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (error) {
          alert.error(error);
          dispatch(clearErrors());
        }
    
        if (success) {
          alert.success("Product Created Successfully");
         navigate("/admin/dashboard");
          dispatch({ type: NEW_PRODUCT_RESET });
        }
        
      }, [dispatch, alert, error, navigate, success]);
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        dispatch(animalTypeLoadAction())
        dispatch(treatmentTypeLoadAction())
        dispatch(dailyEssentialsTypeLoadAction())
        dispatch(medicalCareTypeLoadAction())
      },[dispatch])
      
      const createProductImagesChange = (e) =>{

        const files = Array.from(e.target.files);
    
        setImages([]);
        setImagesPreview([]);
        files.forEach((file) => {
            const reader = new FileReader();
      
            reader.onload = () => {
              if (reader.readyState === 2) {
                setImagesPreview((old) => [...old, reader.result]);
                setImages((old) => [...old, reader.result]);
              }
            };
      
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
          });
    
      }
    
      // handle change for faq
      const handleChange = (index, key, value) => {
        const newFAQs = [...faqs];
        if (!newFAQs[index]) {
          newFAQs[index] = {};
        }
        newFAQs[index][key] = value;
        setFAQs(newFAQs);
      };


      //render faqs input 
      const renderFAQInputs = () => {
        const inputs = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          inputs.push(
            <div key={i}>
              <FiHelpCircle />
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder={`Question ${i + 1}`}
                value={faqs[i] && faqs[i].question ? faqs[i].question : ""}
                onChange={(e) => handleChange(i, "question", e.target.value)}
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder={`Answer ${i + 1}`}
                value={faqs[i] && faqs[i].answer ? faqs[i].answer : ""}
                onChange={(e) => handleChange(i, "answer", e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
          );
        }
        return inputs;
      };
    

const createProductSubmitHandler =(e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const myForm = new FormData()

    myForm.set("name", name);
    myForm.set("price", price);
    myForm.set("description", description);
    myForm.set("Stock", Stock);
    myForm.set("animal", animal);
    myForm.set("treatment", treatment);
    myForm.set("dailyEssential", dailyEssential);
    myForm.set("medicalCare", medicalCare);
    myForm.set("brand", brand);
    myForm.set("size_of_instrument", size_of_instrument);
    myForm.set("stage", stage);
    myForm.set("condition", condition);
    myForm.set("varieties", varieties);
    myForm.set("specific_feature", specific_feature);
    myForm.set("packaging_dimensions", packaging_dimensions);
    myForm.set("mode_of_administration", mode_of_administration);
    myForm.set("caution", caution);
    myForm.set("material_used", material_used);
    myForm.set("model_number", model_number);
    myForm.set("weight_of_the_commodity", weight_of_the_commodity);
    myForm.set("shelflife", shelflife);
    myForm.set("guarantee", guarantee);
    
    for (let i = 0; i < faqs.length; i++) {
        myForm.set(`faqs[${i}][question]`, faqs[i].question);
        myForm.set(`faqs[${i}][answer]`, faqs[i].answer);
        console.log(myForm.get(`faqs[${i}][question]`));
        console.log(myForm.get(`faqs[${i}][answer]`));     
     }
      
    images.forEach((image) => {
        myForm.append("images", image);
      });
    dispatch(createProduct(myForm))
    
}

  return (
    <>
  <MetaData title="Create Product -Admin" />
    <div className="dashboard">
    <Sidebar />
    <div className="newProductContainer">
        <form 
         className='createProductForm'
         encType='multipart/form-data'
         onSubmit={createProductSubmitHandler}
        >
        <h1>Create Product</h1> 
        <div>
            <MdSpellcheck />
            <input 
            type="text"
            placeholder='Product Name'
            required
            value={name}
            onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
            />
        </div>
        <div>
            <MdAttachMoney />
            <input 
            type="number"
            placeholder='Price'
            required
            onChange={(e) => setPrice(e.target.value)}
            />
        </div>
        <div>
              <MdDescription />

              <textarea
                placeholder="Product Description"
                value={description}
                onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
                cols="30"
                rows="1"
              ></textarea>
            </div>

            <div>
              <MdAccountTree />
              <select onChange={(e) => setAnimal(e.target.value)}>
                <option value="">Choose Animal Type</option>
                {animalType && animalType.map((cate) => (
                  <option key={cate._id} value={cate._id}>
                    {cate.animalName}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </select>
            </div>

            <div>
              <MdAccountTree />
              <select onChange={(e) => setTreatment(e.target.value)}>
                <option value="">Choose Treatment Type</option>
                {treatmentType && treatmentType.map((cate) => (
                  <option key={cate._id} value={cate._id}>
                    {cate.TreatmentTypeName}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </select>
            </div>

            <div>
              <MdAccountTree />
              <select onChange={(e) => setmedicalCare(e.target.value)}>
                <option value="">Choose Medical Care</option>
                {MedicalCareType && MedicalCareType.map((cate) => (
                  <option key={cate._id} value={cate._id}>
                    {cate.medicalCareName}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </select>
            </div>

            <div>
              <MdAccountTree />
              <select onChange={(e) => setdailyEssential(e.target.value)}>
                <option value="">Choose dailyEssential</option>
                {dailyEssentialType && dailyEssentialType.map((cate) => (
                  <option key={cate._id} value={cate._id}>
                    {cate.essentialName}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </select>
            </div>

            <div>
              <MdStorage />
              <input
                type="number"
                placeholder="Stock"
                required
                onChange={(e) => setStock(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>

            <div>
            <FiPenTool />
            <input 
            type="text"
            placeholder='Brand Name'
            required
            onChange={(e) => setBrand(e.target.value)}
            />
        </div>  
        <div>
  <FiPenTool />
  <input 
    type="text"
    placeholder="Size of Instrument"
    onChange={(e) => setSize_of_instrument(e.target.value)}
  />
</div>

<div>
  <FiPenTool />
  <input 
    type="text"
    placeholder="Stage"
    onChange={(e) => setstage(e.target.value)}
  />
</div>

<div>
  <FiPenTool />
  <input 
    type="text"
    placeholder="Condition"
    onChange={(e) => setCondition(e.target.value)}
  />
</div>

<div>
  <FiPenTool />
  <input 
    type="text"
    placeholder="Varieties"
    onChange={(e) => setvarieties(e.target.value)}
  />
</div>

<div>
  <FiPenTool />
  <input 
    type="text"
    placeholder="Specific Feature"
    onChange={(e) => setSpecific_feature(e.target.value)}
  />
</div>

<div>
  <FiPenTool />
  <input 
    type="text"
    placeholder="Packaging Dimensions"
    onChange={(e) => setPackaging_dimensions(e.target.value)}
  />
</div>

<div>
  <FiPenTool />
  <input 
    type="text"
    placeholder="Mode of Administration"
    onChange={(e) => setMode_of_administration(e.target.value)}
  />
</div>

<div>
  <FiPenTool />
  <input 
    type="text"
    placeholder="Caution"
    onChange={(e) => setCaution(e.target.value)}
  />
</div>

<div>
  <FiPenTool />
  <input 
    type="text"
    placeholder="Material Used"
    onChange={(e) => setMaterial_used(e.target.value)}
  />
</div>

<div>
  <FiPenTool />
  <input 
    type="text"
    placeholder="Model Number"
    onChange={(e) => setModel_number(e.target.value)}
  />
</div>

<div>
  <FiPenTool />
  <input 
    type="text"
    placeholder="Weight of the Commodity"
    onChange={(e) => setweight_of_the_commodity(e.target.value)}
  />
</div>

<div>
  <FiPenTool />
  <input 
    type="text"
    placeholder="Shelf Life"
    onChange={(e) => setShelflife(e.target.value)}
  />
</div>

<div>
  <FiPenTool />
  <input 
    type="text"
    placeholder="Guarantee"
    onChange={(e) => setGuarantee(e.target.value)}
  />
    </div>
    <Typography>Faq Question and answer</Typography>
    <div>{renderFAQInputs()}</div>

    <Typography>Choose Images</Typography>

        <div id="createProductFormFile">
              <input
                type="file"
                name="avatar"
                accept="image/*"
                onChange={createProductImagesChange}
                multiple
              />
            </div>
    
    <div id="createProductFormImage">
        {imagesPreview.map((image, index) => (
            <img key={index} src={image} alt="Product Preview" />
        ))}
            </div>
            <Button
              id="createProductBtn"
              type="submit"
              disabled={loading ? true : false}
            >
              Create
            </Button>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default NewProduct
```

productAction.js

```
// Create Product Admin
export const createProduct = (productData) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: NEW_PRODUCT_REQUEST });

    const config = {
      headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
    };

    const { data } = await axios.post(
      `/api/v1/product/create`,
      productData,
      config
    );

    dispatch({
      type: NEW_PRODUCT_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: NEW_PRODUCT_FAIL,
      payload: error.response.data.message,
    });
  }
};







//productModel.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema;

const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:[true,"Please enter Product name"]
    },
    description:{
        type:String,
        required:[true, "Please enter the product description"]
    },
    price:{
        type:Number,
        required:[true,"Please Enter the product price"],
        maxLength:[8,"Price cannot exceed 8 char"]
    },
    ratings:{
        type:Number,
        default:0
    },
    brand:{
        type:String,
        required:[true, "Please enter the product brand"]
    },
    size_of_instrument:{
        type: [String],
        default: []
    },
    stage:{
        type:String,
        default:"all stage"
    },
    condition:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },
    varieties:{
        type: [String],
        default: []
    },
    specific_feature:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    packaging_dimensions:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    mode_of_administration: {
        type: String,
    },
    caution:{
        type:String,
    },
    material_used:{
        type: String,
        required:true
    },
    Stock:{
        type:Number,
        required:[true,"Please Enter product stock"],
        maxLength:[10,"Stock cannot exceed 4 characters"],
        default:1
    },
    color:[
        {
            type:String,
        }
    ],
    model_number:{
        type:String
    },
    weight_of_the_commodity:{
        type:String
    },
    shelflife:{
        type:Number,
    },
    guarantee:{
        type:Number
    },
    images:[
        {
            public_id:{
                type:String,
                required:true
            },
            url:{
                type:String,
                required:true
            }
        }
    ],
    numOfReviews:{
        type:Number,
        default:0
    },
    reviews:[
        {
            user:{
                type:ObjectId,
                ref:"User",
                required:true
            },
            name:{
                type:String,
                required:true,
            },
            rating:{
                type:Number,
            },
            comment:{
                type:String,
            }

        }
    ],
    user:{
        type:ObjectId,
        ref:"User",
        required:true
    },
    animal:{
        type:ObjectId,
        ref:"Animal",
        required:true
    },
    treatment:{
        type:ObjectId,
        ref:"Treatment",
    },
    dailyEssential:{
        type:ObjectId,
        ref:"Essential",
    },
    medicalCare:{
        type:ObjectId,
        ref:"Medical",
    },
    faqs: [
        {
           question:{
            type:String,
           },
           answer:{
            type:String
           }
        },
      ],
    createdAt:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Product", ProductSchema);


Product Controller.js
//create product
exports.createProduct = catchAsyncError(async (req, res, next) => {
    try {


      let images = [];

      if(typeof req.body.images === "string"){
          images.push(req.body.images)
      }else{
          images = req.body.images;
      }
  
      const imagesLink = [];
      for(let i =0 ; i<images.length; i++){
          const result =  await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(images[i],{
              folder: "products",
          })
          imagesLink.push({
              public_id:result.public_id,
              url:result.secure_url
          })
      }

       req.body.images = imagesLink;

        req.body.user = req.user.id;

        const product = await Product.create(req.body);

        res.status(201).json({
            success: true,
            product,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
});
```